# Handling Permissions Below Android M

Tags: android

Does anyone know how to handle dangerous permissions such as permission for camera,storage etc. Below Android Version Marshmallow.
I know how to request permission above Android marshmallow but how handle it for the version below it? 
Any Solution?

Comment: For versions < Android M, you do not require permissions at runtime. Just mention them in the manifest file and they will be auto granted as user has to accept those at time of installation.  If you want, you can show a dialog to your user before accessing a resource that requires a dangerous permission as an extra check.

Comment: But why in some phones the activity on which I requested the permission to access storage doesn't opens and even the app doesn't crashes at all.

Comment: Can you post the code snippet so I can better assess the issue? Does the permission dialog doesn't open or your internal storage directory?

Comment: Generally the permission dialog always opens on devices whose Android version is greater than api 23.. but as this feature is not available for devices below it. It doesn't opens as I have applied a try catch for that

Comment: It will never open for devices below Android M. They already grant permission if its mentioned in manifest so u need no extra checks there. Add a check that if android version < M, just access the storage directly.

Comment: Ok i will definitely try that stuff. Thanks for your support

Answer (score 2):

You don't need extra codes to handle permission below marshmallow. Permission set on manifest works just fine.